How to cast property of type Integer to Edm.Int64
I am querying a OData V2 service to fetch group members.
The request that I tried is: /odata/v2/getUsersByDynamicGroup?groupId=6914&activeOnly=true.
The query param groupId should be Edm.Int64.
On the other hand, I supplied the group ID from /odata/v2/DynamicGroup response.
How can I cast the groupId to work as Edm.Int64?

The solution was to add "L" into the integer.
/odata/v2/getUsersByDynamicGroup?groupId=6914L&activeOnly=true
